# What is a 'k' packet?

Tags: macos, debugging, crash, core-audio

I have this crash log on a Core Audio application I'm developping. I'm currently debugging it, so my question isn't about the crash itself, but about the meaning of **'k' packet**.

What does it mean ?

I've read [this](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2013-04/msg00658.html), and [this](http://osdir.com/ml/gdb.devel/2002-08/msg00020.html) (about inferior process), but I'm not sure to understand.

**CRASH LOG EXTRACT**

> 26/05/14 15:12:37,469 coreaudiod[170]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,352 com.apple.debugserver-300.2[1587]: **Got a 'k' packet, killing the inferior process.**
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,353 com.apple.debugserver-300.2[1587]: Sending ptrace PT_KILL to terminate
>   inferior process.
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,353 com.apple.debugserver-300.2[1587]: 2 +70.908045 sec [0633/0303]: error: ::ptrace (request = PT_THUPDATE, pid = 0x0634, tid = 0x2003, signal = 0) err = Resource busy (0x00000010)
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,354 com.apple.debugserver-300.2[1587]: 3 +0.000258 sec [0633/0303]: error: ::task_info ( target_task = 0x1803, flavor = TASK_BASIC_INFO, task_info_out => 0x7fff5a8ecfa0, task_info_outCnt => 10 ) err = (os/kern) invalid argument (0x00000004)
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,362 coreaudiod[170]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,369 _coreaudiod[1607]: audit warning: allsoft 26/05/14 15:13:40,369 _coreaudiod[1606]: audit warning: soft/var/audit
>
> 26/05/14 15:13:40,370 _coreaudiod[1608]: audit warning: closefile /var/audit/20140526131229.20140526131340

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A k Packet is a [kill command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html), received by GDB and executed upon the "inferior process," to wit, killing the application being debugged.

GDB can be controlled by a remote machine, and the commands it receives remotely (or locally through the interface) are in the form of formatted TCP packets, hence the name.

Comment: This is a technical quibble, the substance of the answer is correct.  The kill packet is sent FROM the debugger (could be gdb though it is more likely lldb in this case) to the debug agent that is actually managing your process.  On Mac OS X lldb doesn't directly control the process it is debugging, it always creates a debug agent - called debugserver - and communicates with it using the gdb remote protocol - of which the k packet is one instance.  The sequence you are seeing here is what you would normally see if you hit the "stop" button in Xcode while the app is alive.